# Json To XML in XSLT3.0

Tags: json, xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

I have the following XML. I have the following XSLT. This XSLT works has a for-each logic that works on XML as required. Now that I want thhis same logic to be applied on a json file, So I understand that I have to first write somejsonToXML logic in my XSLT and also have this for-each. I am not getting how to do that. can anybody please help me..  I have the required Json below. This is nothin but the conversion of XML.

XML is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Records>
        <Record>
            <Field name="Second Name" alias="Second_Name">Lilly</Field>
            <Field name="Last Name" alias="Last_Name">James</Field>
            <Field name="Middle Name" alias="Middle_Name">J</Field>
            <Field name="Address" alias="Address">R C Villa</Field>
            <Field name="City" alias="City">Pagarh</Field>
            <Field name="State" alias="State">Kansas</Field>
            <Field name="Zip Code" alias="Zip_Code">8878</Field>
        </Record>
    </Records>
```

XSLT that works fine for the above XML is below:

```
        <?xml version='1.0'?>
        <xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output media-type="xml" indent="yes"/>

        <!--Attributes are not supported at all levels, as well as to allow for each field 
        to be mappable you would need to change the element names to be unique before being consumed through Data Feed.-->

        <xsl:template match="/">
        <Records>
            <xsl:for-each select="Records/Record">
                <Record>
                    <xsl:for-each select="Field">
                        <xsl:element name="{@alias}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </Record>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Records>
        </xsl:template>

        </xsl:stylesheet><!-- Stylus Studio meta-information - (c) 2004-2009. Progress Software Corporation. All rights reserved.

        -->
```

If I have the below Json, what will be the XSLT 3.0?

```
    {
      "Records": {
        "Record": [
          {
            "Field": [
              {
                "-name": "Second Name",
                "-alias": "Second_Name",
                "#text": "James"
              },
              {
                "-name": "Last Name",
                "-alias": "Last_Name",
                "#text": "Shcol"
              },
              {
                "-name": "Middle Name",
                "-alias": "Middle_Name",
                "#text": "J"
              },
              {
                "-name": "Address",
                "-alias": "Address",
                "#text": "BishusPame"
              },
              {
                "-name": "City",
                "-alias": "City",
                "#text": "Hitlas"
              },
              {
                "-name": "State",
                "-alias": "State",
                "#text": "Vietnam"
              }
        ]
      }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? We generally don't write code for you from scratch as this is not a code-writing service. You are expected to make an attempt yourself first. Please visit the [help] and read [ask] for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.

You could parse the JSON (using `parse-json()` or `json-doc()`) to a structure of maps and arrays, and then operate on the maps and arrays.

Alternatively, you could convert the JSON to XML (using `json-to-xml()`), and then operate on the XML.

I gave some worked examples of both approaches in my paper at XML Prague 2016, which you can read here: https://www.saxonica.com/papers/xmlprague-2016mhk.pdf -- the overall conclusion was that the second approach was probably easier for many use cases. But your processing is so simple that either would work perfectly well.

More recently I've been working on some Saxon extensions that are designed to make the first approach more powerful: see http://dev.saxonica.com/blog/mike/2017/11/transforming-json.html (though this is not yet available in product).

If you use the `parse-json()`/`json-doc()` approach then I think it would look like this (untested):

```
<xsl:for-each select="json-doc($json-uri)?Records?Record?*">
  <Record>
    <xsl:for-each select="?Field?*">
      <xsl:element name="{?('-alias')}">{?('#text')}</xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </Record>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Note the "?*" is needed to turn an array into a sequence, because `xsl:for-each` will iterate over a sequence, but not over an array.

(The example uses a *Text Value Template* so it assumes `expand-text="yes"` at the stylesheet level, which I include in XSLT 3.0 by default).